# Combing several random events into a single calculation while maintaining the same standard deviation

Tags: probability

I'm simulating a number of low probability random events and I want to get the total number that occur with $n$ simulations (not the expected number, the actually number) by rolling a single random number. So going from this

$N = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n  
\begin{cases}
    1,& \text{if } random(0,1)\leq p\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}  $

Where $p$ is the probability of each single event occurring, and random(0,1) is an evenly distributed random function outputting between 0 and 1, $N$ is the number of events that succeed and $n$ is the number of tries.

Getting the expected number is easy $N_e = pn$. but I'm looking to actually run this with a real random number generator and get the actual result (e.g. in a toss of 300 coins you'll expect to get 150 heads but you might get 300)

Effectively what I'm trying to do is to eliminate the sum in a way that maintains the standard deviation and make only a single call to the function random(0,1)

In the case of flipping 3 coins with probability 0.5 I'd therefore expand this to:

$N = 
\begin{cases}
    3, & 0.875 \lt r \leq 1\\
    2, & 0.5 \lt r \leq 0.875\\
    1,& 0.125 \lt r \leq 0.5 \\
    0, &0 \lt r \leq 0.125 \\
\end{cases}  $

where r is a single call to random(0,1)

But that is obviously a very specific case, expecially the 0.5 probability which makes everything easier, is there a way to do this in the general case?

Answer (score 0):

The probability of getting a particular number of successes is:

$P_N = numberOfCombinations * probabilityOfCombination $

$P_N = \frac{n!}{N!(n-N)!} p^Np^{(n-N)}$

where $N$ is the number of successes, $n$ is the number of tries and $p$ is the probability of success

So this is the size of the region that should be mapped to the $r$, what region it is doesn't really matter, so the region of the single call to $random(0,1)$ that $r$ should take to provide $N$ successes is:

$  \sum\limits_{m=1}^{N-1}   \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!} p^mp^{(n-m)} \lt r \lt \sum\limits_{m=1}^{N}   \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!} p^mp^{(n-m)} $